# When I try to dispatch an action I am getting an error dispatch is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am new to redux and trying to learn everything from scratch.
- so I too an npm package and implementing in my form
- when I try to dispatch an action I am getting an error dispatch is not defined
- can you let me know how to fix it. I looked into the documentaion
  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-loading-bar
- I debugged by putting console but still I am not able to fix it.
- can you tell me how to fix so that infuture I will fix it myself.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/zn812n05v4

```
const SyncValidationForm = props => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  console.log("handleSubmit--->", handleSubmit);
  console.log("handleSubmit props--->", props);
  dispatch(showLoading("sectionBar"));
  return (
    <div>
      <LoadingBar />

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          name="username"
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Username"
        />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dispatch is passed through `props`. use `props.dispatch` instead

Comment: hey can we pass dispatch through state...can you tell the reson, it will help me to understand more and loading bar should show only onsubmit of the forms

Comment: hmm what do you mean by pass through state? `reduxForm(opts)` is a higher order componentv and using `reduxForm(opts)(Component)` will inject dispatch to your component. In your SyncValidationForm.js `reduxForm(opts)(SyncValidationForm)` , so your SyncValidationForm component has access to `dispatch`. If you just need to show loading bar on form submit, you dont need to use state. Just in your form submit function use something like `dispatch(loadingAction)`

Comment: so do I need to use it as handleSubmit.dispatch(showLoading("sectionBar")) or in some other way...can you please help me...ist so confusing...can you update in my sandbox directly :(

Comment: Your form submit handler is inside showResult.js. Since that is just a utility function and not a component so it has no access to dispatch itself so it is better to import `store` and use `store.dispatch`. Take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/1vq8j73jn4

Comment: hey still I got confused without importing the store cant I achieve in showResults.js...is there any other way...whats the main use of store...and since component is not created here are you saying it as an utility function

Comment: hey I used your same logic in my application and my loading bar code is in ReceipeReviewCardList.js but its not working...its inside the method getPlayerssData can you tell me whats the problem is https://codesandbox.io/s/kxqppprjv

Comment: can you help me with tgis one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54084760/file-merge-using-react-in-material-ui

Answer (score 0):

Dispatch can be used in many ways:

```
import store from './store.js'; // add this in SyncValidationForm.js

dispatch(...); // replace this
store.dispatch(...); // use this instead
```

However, I'd recommend dispatching actions through [react-redux's connect](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013), that allows to dispatch actions directly from props, and is more generally regarded as *the React way* to dispatch actions.